# Trying to get margin top of 10px for all my elements of the form

Tags: html, css

Im doing a login box with a form, that asks for email and password.

I have all my elements in vertical, and Im trying to align all elements to stay with 10px margin top and bottom, to get every element with the same space.

But Im not having sucess to this goal, can you give some help understanding what I have wrong?

I give some backgrounds to my elements to be more easy to see how are the margins, and some backgrounds do not appear as they should, it seems there should also be some problem with floats.

This is my jsfiddle with what Im getting:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hp8zV/1/

My html:

```
<body>
<div class="loginbox">
    <h1>Login Form:</h1>
    <span class="ms in">Enter your acess data.</span>
    <form name="login">
        <label class="label">
            <input placeholder="Email" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label class="label">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Pass"  class="pass"  />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn" />
            <a href="#" class="link">Forgot</a>
        </label>        
    </form>    
</div>
</body>
```

My Css:

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body{overflow:hidden;}

.loginbox{position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%;background:#f7f7f7; width:360px; height:340px;}
.loginbox{margin-left:-180px; margin-top:-162px; background:pink;}
.loginbox h1{padding:20px; font-weight:200; color:#fff; background:brown; font-size:30px;}
.loginbox form{padding:20px; background:yellow;}
.loginbox form .label{display:block; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px; float:left; width:320px;background:green;}
.loginbox form .label input{padding:10px; font-size:16px; border:1px solid #CCC; width:299px; float:left;}
.loginbox form .label .pass{width:299px; float:left;}
.loginbox form .label .btn{float:right; width:auto; display:block; background:brown; border:none; text-transform:uppercase; margin:20px auto;}
.loginbox form .label .btn{padding:11px 10px 11px; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; width:320px;}
.loginbox form .link {text-align:center; text-decoration:none; color:#000; background:blue;}

.ms{padding:20px 10px 5px 20px;float:left;display:block;  width:320px; background:red;
```

}

Comment: Tip: Avoid applying CSS styles to the form element.

Comment: Inputs shouldn't be wrapped with labels.

Comment: You should start with this: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Guide/

Comment: Your CSS rules have loads of inconsistencies.

Comment: @MelanciaUK that's legal, it avoids having to use "for" and "id".

Comment: Fair enough. But this won't solve the problem anyway. Thanks for the tip @Bart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your new code:

```
<body>
<div class="loginbox">
    <h1>Login Form:</h1>
    <span class="ms">Enter your acess data.</span>
    <form name="login">
            <input placeholder="Email" type="text"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Pass"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn"/>
            <a href="#">Forgot</a>
    </form>    
</div>
</body>

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
}
.loginbox *{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.loginbox{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    background:#f7f7f7;
    width:360px;
    height:290px;
    margin-left:-180px;
    margin-top:-162px;
    background:pink;
}
.loginbox h1{
    padding:20px;
    font-weight:200;
    color:#fff;
    background:brown;
    font-size:30px;
}
.loginbox form{
    padding:20px;
    background:yellow;
}
.loginbox form input{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:16px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.loginbox form .btn{
    background:brown;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin:10px auto;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100%;}

.ms{
    padding:10px 10px 10px 20px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}
.loginbox form a {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    background:blue;
}
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hp8zV/5/)

Hope i helped you

Comment: Thank you Caio Kawasaki, it worked just fine! By the way do you know how I can center my Forgot link? Because Im trying with text-align:center and margin:0 auto but nothing works.

Comment: Here is the fiddle with the Forgot link centered: http://jsfiddle.net/Hp8zV/6/ , to centralize it, you need to give the parente the text-align:center; not to the child... I even let him on the left, is more beautiful ...